# How to roll back the changes if trigger failed

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I have two table. The `Invoices` table and the `Outputs` table. I want to update table `Outputs` after the Invoices table has been updated. I want to roll back `Invoices` changes if `Outputs` update fails.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[Invoices_InputUpdate]
ON [dbo].[Invoices]
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
 DECLARE @InvoiceId INT;
 SELECT @InvoiceId = InvoiceId From inserted
 UPDATE Outputs SET InvoiceModified=1 WHERE InvoiceId = @InvoiceId 
END
```

Comment: It will automatically rollback if you update fails.

Comment: Of course your trigger doesn't actually do anything useful... you are selecting 1 random id from the invoices table... is what you want? You probably want to make use of the `Inserted` pseudo-table?

Comment: In reference to Dale's comment, the `INSERTED` and `DELETED` virtual tables are, well... tables. They can contain 0, 1 or many rows, so `SELECT @InvoiceId = InvoiceId From inserted` is working from a flawed assumption that the trigger will only be dealing with one row at a time.

Comment: this will fail if more then one invoices are updated, you need something like `update o set o.InvoiceModified = 1 from Outputs o inner join inserted i on o.InvoiceID = i.InvoiceID`

Comment: This is the #1 trigger #fail for people new to writing triggers.

Comment: Its a curious question to ask, because a quick test would show the answer, and you will I assume still test it now...

Comment: **Required** reading: [Bad Habits to Kick : Abusing triggers](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-abusing-triggers) & [The Silent Bug I Find in Most Triggers](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2019/05/the-silent-bug-i-find-in-most-triggers/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AFTER` triggers take place after data is written to the table and are a distinct and separate set of operations that execute as part of the same transaction that wrote to the table, but after that write occurs. If the trigger fails, the original operation also fails.

The code will work fine for a single-row update. However, It fail for a multi-row update. As @GuidoG states in the comments, we can avoid this failure by the following code:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[Invoices_InputUpdate]
ON [dbo].[Invoices]
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
 UPDATE o SET InvoiceModified=1 
 FROM Outputs AS o
 INNER JOIN inserted i on o.InvoiceID = i.InvoiceID
END
```

As I said, if the trigger fails, the original operation also fails and the transaction will rollback.